# Just Installed VS2015, Broken Header Files?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So, I just installed Visual Studio 2015. My OS is Windows 8.1 Embedded (From Dreamspark) and I can't seem to run a simple Hello world program at all without getting errors. (443 to be exact). It's a

```
Error (active)      the global scope has no "log10l"    Project1    c:\Program Files (x86)\Program Files\VC\include\cmath   675 
Error (active)      cannot open source file "errno.h"   Project1    c:\Program Files (x86)\Program Files\VC\include\cerrno  14  
Error (active)      cannot open source file "float.h"   Project1    c:\Program Files (x86)\Program Files\VC\include\cfloat  7   
Error (active)      cannot open source file "math.h"    Project1    c:\Program Files (x86)\Program Files\VC\include\cmath   12  
Error (active)      the global scope has no "acosf" Project1    c:\Program Files (x86)\Program Files\VC\include\xtgmath.h   210 
...
... And so on
... 
Error (active)      explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    Project1    c:\Program Files (x86)\Program Files\VC\include\xtgmath.h   211 
Error (active)      explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    Project1    c:\Program Files (x86)\Program Files\VC\include\xtgmath.h   212 
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory    Project1    c:\program files (x86)\program files\vc\include\crtdefs.h   10
```

My guess is that something might be wrong with the header files, but I reinstalled Visual Studio and that didn't help with anything. Could it be OS related? I'm used to running Visual Studio 2013 on my Laptop w/ Windows 10, but my new computer is running Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8.1 Embedded from Dreamspark.

Just to make sure, this is the simple code that I'm using to test VS.

```
#include <iostream>  
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Hopefully someone will be able to point me towards a solution. Thank you for reading.

Comment: These header files are not installed into the proper directory.  Very hard to guess how they ended up in c:\Program Files (x86)\Program Files\VC, that's a completely nonsensical directory name.  That it cannot find other headers is not surprising.  You'll have to get it installed correctly first before you can get ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 uses the [Universal C Runtime](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/). From the errors you are hitting, you have `c:\Program Files (x86)\Program Files\VC\include` installed, but you are missing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt` from your include path.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General and changed the Windows SDK version to the most current (it was 8.1 and I changed it to 10.0.10586.0) and it cleaned u